# Calling a function after data event in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I wonder what is the best way to do something like this:

When one of the data gets remove, all client will play an animation (like fading out the data, etc), or call a javascript function on client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`cursor.observeChanges`](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe_changes) callbacks are exactly what you need in your client code to achieve this - specifically the `removed` callback.  Have a look at the example provided in the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe_changes) and it should be quite straightforward.

Comment: He'll probably need to use the `added` callback too and add the document to the DOM himself.

Comment: See also https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#how-do-i-animate-things-addingbeing-removed-from-collections